# Определение параметров, с которыми перекодировано видео

Tags: видео, перекодировка, ffmpeg

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли способы определить, с какими параметрами был запущен ffmpeg при конвертации видео?

Например, залить в ВК короткий ролик в разрешении 1920*1080 и необходимо узнать, с какими параметрами был запущен ffmpeg для конвертации в качество 360.
Т.е. у нас есть 2 ролика (оригинал и результат), и нужно понять, как из оригинала получить такой же результат с помощью ffmpeg.

Благодарю за ответы.

С уважением.

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg выводит очень подробную информацию о параметрах кодирования роликов. Вот, например, можно воспользоваться чем-то подобным:

```
ffprobe -print_format json -show_format -show_streams cheshire_cat.mp4
```

что в свою очередь выдаст:

```
ffprobe version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
{
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cheshire_cat.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-03-09 02:08:41
  Duration: 00:05:46.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 364 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 500x276 [SAR 1:1 DAR 125:69], 265 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-09 02:08:47
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Constrained Baseline",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/50",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 276,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "125:69",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 21,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "1",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/25",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 8660,
            "duration": "346.400000",
            "bit_rate": "265582",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "8660",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/44100",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/44100",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 15277056,
            "duration": "346.418503",
            "bit_rate": "95999",
            "nb_frames": "14919",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2014-03-09 02:08:47",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "cheshire_cat.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "346.418333",
        "size": "15764669",
        "bit_rate": "364060",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "mp42",
            "minor_version": "0",
            "compatible_brands": "isommp42",
            "creation_time": "2014-03-09 02:08:41"
        }
    }
}
```